# Force sed to replace the matching line only once in the target file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace

I have following script to replace the specified key-value pairs in PHP INI Configuration file:

```
iniConfigs='memory_limit=3G
short_open_tag=On
post_max_size=512M
max_input_time=3600
max_execution_time=21600
upload_max_filesize=128M
extension_dir="C:\\PHPs\\PHP7032\\ext"'

while IFS= read -r line
do
    key=$(awk -F\= '{print $1}' <<< $line)
    sed -i "s/^\($key\).*/\1 ${line}/" php.ini
done <<< "$iniConfigs"
```

Now here is the problem with `sed`, it doesn't exactly find the line starting with the matching `key` and replace it with corresponding line as expected, which results into something like below in the php.ini:

```
short_open_tag short_open_tag=On
...
max_execution_time max_execution_time=21600
```

instead of,

```
short_open_tag=On
...
max_execution_time=21600
```

Why `sed` doesn't exactly replace the string as expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `\1` in the replacement pattern.  You don't need that because `$line` already has the key.  This will do:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    key=$(awk -F\= '{print $1}' <<< $line)
    sed -i "s/^$key.*/$line/" php.ini
done <<< "$iniConfigs"
```

This code will break if your content has any characters than can confuse `sed`.  For example, `/`.